# Dynamic import with template string as path error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to get dynamic importing working while supporting a dynamic path, but I've noticed the following behavior below:

```
// Using lazy and Suspense API from React

// FAILS
const path = "folder/file"; 

// use `${path}` template string because using variable inside import fails
const LazyModule = lazy(() => import(`${path}`));
return <Suspense fallback={this._getFallback()}><LazyModule></Suspense>;



// SUCCEEDS

// use actual string
const LazyModule = lazy(() => import("folder/file"));
return <Suspense fallback={this._getFallback()}><LazyModule></Suspense>;
```

I read that we cannot use variables inside import statements, but if we convert it  using `"" + <path>` or `` `${path}` ``, I thought this was supposed to solve this issue. However, when I use this, I get the error:
`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module 'folder/file'.`

Is there a known workaround for this behavior?

Using webpack "3.12.0".

Comment: Did you mean to say `node_modules/filename`? 

Also, do you happen to be using `babel`? If so, babel doesn't support the dynamic import syntax and you'll need the plugin `@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import`

Comment: For my path, sometimes it points to `node_modules`, and sometimes it points to a relative path like "../components/file". I'm also already using `syntax-dynamic-import` and `dynamic-import-webpack`

Comment: try adding `return` before the import?

`const LazyModule = lazy(() => return import('${path}'));`

Comment: @Mike, fat arrows have an implicit return if you don't wrap the function in braces.